# Loop only works if I comment out a line... pulling my hair out over this

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have the following code, that includes a simple loop.

To test it, I have included a simple print(x) statement, so i can confirm the loop works.

```
def findResistanceCurve(stock_hist, timeFactor, curveType):

   my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start date', 'Confirmations', 'Latest conf date', 'Latest resistance value'])
   bestRstart           = np.nan
   priceBestR           = np.nan
   noBestRconfirmed     = np.nan    
   startHighR           = np.nan
   priceHighR           = np.nan
   noHighestRConfirmed  = np.nan
   startLatestR         = np.nan
   priceLatestR         = np.nan
   noLatestRConfirmed   = np.nan
   length               = len(stock_hist)
   n                    = 5
   launchpoints         = list(argrelextrema(stock_hist['high'].values, np.greater_equal, axis =0, order = n))

   newlist      = launchpoints[0].tolist()

   if newlist: 
       startLatestR = newlist[-1]
       newlist = [x for x in newlist if x <= length - 5] 
       templist = []
       for a in newlist:
           val1 = a + 1
           val2 = a + 2
           val3 = a + 3
           templist.append(val1)
           templist.append(val2)
           templist.append(val3)
           templist2  = newlist + templist
       final_new_list = list(dict.fromkeys(templist2))
   else:
       final_new_list = newlist
    
   for x in final_new_list:  # A LIST OF INTEGERS TO LOOP OVER
       print('x is', x) # <- DOES NOT LOOP AS EXPECTED, STOPS AT FIRST VALUE
       dft        = stock_hist.copy().iloc[x:]
       curve      = calcCurve(dft, 'R'); 
       confResult = confirmCurve(curve, curveType, .01, .01, 1) # LOOPS ONLY IF I COMMENT THIS LINE OUT
       curve_data = {'Start date': x,
                  'Latest resistance value': curve.iloc[-1]['Curve']
                 }
       my_df      = my_df.append(curve_data, ignore_index = True)
       confResult = confirmCurve(curve, curveType, .01, .01, 1)

       if x == startLatestR:
           priceLatestR       = curve.iloc[-1]['high'] / curve.iloc[-1]['Curve']
           noLatestRConfirmed = len(result.index)


   if my_df.empty == False:
       my_df               = my_df.sort_values(['Confirmations'], ascending = (False))
       bestRstart          = my_df.iloc[0]['Start date']
       noBestRconfirmed    = my_df.iloc[0]['Confirmations']
       priceBestR          = curve.iloc[-1]['high'] / my_df.iloc[0]['Latest resistance value']
       my_df               = my_df.sort_values(['Latest resistance value'], ascending = (False))
       startHighR          = my_df.iloc[0]['Start date']
       priceHighR          = curve.iloc[-1]['high'] / my_df.iloc[0]['Latest resistance value']
       my_df               = my_df.sort_values(['Latest resistance value'], ascending = (False))
       noHighestRConfirmed = my_df.iloc[0]['Confirmations']
       my_df               = my_df.sort_values(['Start date'], ascending = (False))
       noLatestRConfirmed  = my_df.iloc[0]['Confirmations']

   return bestRstart, priceBestR, noBestRconfirmed, startHighR,  priceHighR, noHighestRConfirmed, startLatestR, priceLatestR, noLatestRConfirmed
```

For some reason, the `for x in final_new_list:` loop ONLY works if I comment out the line `confResult = confirmCurve(curve, curveType, .01, .01, 1)` but the call to that function is key to what I need to do.

I am completely pulling my hair out over this.... Why on earth does the loop stop at the first value?

edit: The confirmCurve code looks like so:

```
def confirmCurve(curve, curve_type, sense_below =.05, sense_above = .05, b=2):
    
    # Reworked for both resistance and support
    b              = 5
    df             = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Distance', 'Porosity', 'OBV', 'OBV_rel'])
    testNeeded     = False

    curve['av_price']        = .5* (curve['high'] + curve['low'])
    curve['OBV']             = np.where(curve['av_price'] > curve['av_price'].shift(1), curve['volume'], np.where(curve['av_price'] < curve['av_price'].shift(1), -curve['volume'], 0)).cumsum() 
    curve['OBV_rolling_max'] = curve['OBV'].expanding(1).max()
    curve['OBV_rel']         = curve['OBV']/curve['OBV_rolling_max'] 
    df             = curve.copy().iloc[2:]
    
    if curve_type == 'S':
        df['testdata']      = df['low']/df['Curve']
        df['test_for_conf'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.testdata.values, np.less_equal, order=b)[0]]['testdata']
        df['max']           = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.testdata.values, np.greater_equal, order=b)[0]]['testdata']
        df.loc[(df['test_for_conf']< (1 + sense_above)) & (df['test_for_conf']> (1 - sense_below) ), 'confirmation'] = True
 #       df['porosity'] = df['low'] - df['Curve']
 #       df.loc[(df['test_for_conf'] < 1) , 'test_for_conf'] = df.loc[(df['test_for_conf'] > 1) ,-df['porosity']]

    else:
        df                     = curve.copy().iloc[1:]
        df['testdata']         = df['high']/df['Curve']
        df['test_for_conf']    = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.testdata.values, np.greater_equal, order=b)[0]]['testdata']
        df['max']           = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.testdata.values, np.less_equal, order=b)[0]]['testdata']
        df.loc[(df['test_for_conf']< (1 + sense_above)) & (df['test_for_conf']> (1 - sense_below) ), 'confirmation'] = True
        df.loc[df['test_for_conf']> 1, 'porosity'] = df['test_for_conf'] - 1
#        df['porosity'] = df['high'] - df['Curve']
#        df.loc[df['test_for_conf']> 1, 'porosity'] = - df['porosity']
        df.loc[(df['test_for_conf'] > 1) , 'test_for_conf'] = df.loc[(df['test_for_conf'] > 1) ,-df['porosity']]


    df['max'] = df['max'].fillna(method='ffill')
    df['distance'] = abs(df['test_for_conf'] - 1)
    df.dropna(subset = ['confirmation'], inplace = True)
#    print(df)
#    columnsToDrop = ['high', 'low', 'Price', 'P_x_Vol', 'd', 'Cum_P_vol', 'volume','Curve',
#             'testdata', 'test_for_conf', 'max', 'confirmation',
#            'av_price', 'OBV', 'OBV_rolling_max']
#    df.drop(columnsToDrop, inplace = True, axis = 1)
    
    
    return df
```

Comment: You haven't included the definition of `confirmCurve`.

Comment: It's possible that `confirmCurve` is changing `final_new_list`...

Comment: @michalwa confirmCurve is another function, just like calcCurve in the line above.

Comment: @BartBarnard no, it doesn't. confirmCurve simply returns a dataframe with results from a calculation. Doesn't affect final_new_list at all

Comment: Can you just post the code?

Comment: @Michalwa will add above

Comment: Is it possible that `confirmCurve` is throwing an exception? e.g. in the division `df['high']/df['Curve']`?

Comment: @BartBarnard no, that is impossible. Have checked. confirmCurve works as expected.

Comment: Let's go back to a top-level question...  what happens when the loop "fails" does the loop complete for the single element as evidenced by follow-on execution or does it throw an error or does it never come back from the confirmCurve call?

Comment: @airSquid that is the weird thing.... it doesn't throw an error. It produces the result as expected for just that first iteration. But then it stops

Comment: Well your code is pretty gnarly...  It would be a big ask to have somebody walk it out unless there is something glaringly odd.  Chances are there is something with some other element of code or name collision or something.  I'd recommend you set up a logger and start logging different key points in code.  Or go the poor-man's route with a littering of print statements.  And/or mock up the confirmCurve function just to return some dummy variable as a T/S method.

Comment: Have you tried putting `print(final_new_list)` before and after the line you comment out?

Comment: @Axe319   yes i have, and the print statement confirms the final_new_list variable is the list of integers expected

Comment: Did you print them around every function call within your for loop? Your `list` seems to be mutating somewhere. Logging or print statements are your best bet at finding out where.

Comment: Also, is there a way we can get an actual working example to play around with? It's tough to tell what's wrong when there's a possibility that the problem isn't in the code you've given.

Comment: @axe319 yes, i've been generous with print statements to confirm. List isn't mutated. Wrt your second question: The code itself only works with zipline data on the quantopian platform.